# Vuetify add class on certain grid size

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to only add a class to the `v-flex` if the grid size of the element is `xs` (so only on mobile). The code below shows the thought process behind it. However this doesn't work, so how can I apply a class that only on a certain grid size?

```
   <v-flex xs12 lg6 :class="{'roomPadding': xs != visible }">
      <p> My room </p>
   </v-flex>
```

Comment: You've forgot to add your question

Comment: `:class="{'roomPadding': $vuetify.breakpoint.xs}"`    

see docs [breakpoint object](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/grid#breakpoint-object) and [visibility](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/display#visibility)

Comment: @Traxo Perfect that helps, thanks! For anyone curious on how to apply the class to every grid element except `xs` it is: `{'room': true != $vuetify.breakpoint.xs }`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use breakpoint:

`:class="{'roomPadding': $vuetify.breakpoint.xs}"`

See docs about [breakpoint object](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/grid#breakpoint-object) and [visibility](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/display#visibility)

If you want to apply the class to every breakpoint (i.e. screen-size) **except** `xs`, you can use:

`:class="{'roomPadding': !$vuetify.breakpoint.xs}"` (notice `!`)
or
`:class="{'roomPadding': $vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp}"`

because breakpoints return boolean value.
You can get current breakpoint name (string) with `vuetify.breakpoint.name`

Comment: I do not know why this does not work for me. For instance: `'font-weight-bold': $vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown`

Comment: @Begueradj What do you mean "does not work"? Check error log, or see if you applied the class in the first place on the correct element, or provide more code. It must "work". Sometimes vuetify uses `content-class` instead of `class`, so all depends what you really are trying to achieve and what do you mean by "does not work".

Comment: There is one typical case where this does not work: [page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179456/applying-classes-on-specific-viewport-breakpoints-behaves-weirdly-on-page-refres)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this, it is not working

```
<v-app :class="{'pagemargin': !$vuetify.breakpoint.xs}">
```

But this worked when I used vuetify class

```
<v-app :class="{'yellow': !$vuetify.breakpoint.xs}">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the next version (3) in beta, to do this I had to do the following:

```
<v-card-title :class="{ 'ma-0 pa-0': $vuetify.display.xs }">
```