# Applying classes on specific viewport breakpoints behaves weirdly on page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

- Stack: Nuxt.js + Vuetify.js
- Issue: Setting classes depending on breakpoint behaves abnormally
- Attempt:
  In **~/components/SubComponent.vue** I want to display text with large font on small screens and over, and colorize my text in red only on small screens:

  ```
  <v-flex
    xs12
    sm4
    :class="{
      'display-3': $vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp,
      'red--text': $vuetify.breakpoint.xs
    }">
    Sub component
  </v-flex>
  ```
- Output: Whenever I **refresh**, I see the text is red and small on small screens (my laptop).
- Note: I get weird behaviors with this approach whenever I try to combine more classes carefully, but here I am just providing a minimalist example.
- Question: Why this happens and how to overcome it?
- In case you are curious this is a link to reproduce the issue: [here](https://github.com/begueradj/bug-vuetify-apply-classes-breakpoints)

Comment: could you provide a running example like [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54094579/missing-a-default-scoped-slot/54097082#54097082) in order to debug it ?

Comment: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/yyxml886z) a link to codesandbox to get started